# Rarita-Schwinger Equation in solids?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, solid-state-physics, higher-spin

Can this equation, at least in its non-relativistic limit "if it exist" in 3 dimensional, model holes in the valence band for Zinc blende semiconductor materials for example, since in three dimesions, spinors have two dimensions "Pauli spinors", when coupling with vectors $\ell=1$ $\rightarrow$ $D_{1/2} \otimes \Gamma_{\ell=1}$, gives six 3/2 mixed states, when doing a proper $k.p$ computation we arrive at a 6 by 6 Hamiltonian that drives these states, is it possible to associate this Hamiltonian with the Rarita-Schwinger Equation, in three dimension.